# MultinomialNB predict_proba doesnt return labels with the probability

Tags: machine-learning, python, multilabel-classification, nlp

I have a model what looks like this

```
Product_names= [
    'Dress white',
    'Pullover shirt',
    'etc'


]

category_labels = [
   'Female->Clothes->T-shirts',
   'Female->Jeans->Skinny',
   'etc'
]
```

I use the  MultinomialNB classifier to predict a new product name into a category. Before  it gets predicted i want to get the probability of the prediction.

So in psuedo it looks likes this:

```
clf = MultinomialNB()  
clf.fit(Product_names,category_labels)   
clf.predict_proba('White Pullover shirt')
```

What I get is this:

```
[4.18600796e-03 7.46021220e-04 4.14456233e-05 4.14456233e-05
 1.16047745e-03 6.92141910e-03 3.70938329e-03 1.78216180e-03
 1.49204244e-03 2.15517241e-03 1.03614058e-04 3.48143236e-03
 3.27420424e-03 7.66744032e-04 1.03614058e-03 8.91080902e-04
 8.49635279e-04 2.07228117e-04 4.14456233e-05 4.14456233e-05
 2.44529178e-03 1.84433024e-03 1.67854775e-03 1.01541777e-03
 5.28431698e-03 1.03614058e-03 1.45059682e-04 8.28912467e-05
 9.53249337e-04 1.86505305e-03 2.59035146e-03 2.32509947e-02
 1.24336870e-04 6.21684350e-05 2.69396552e-04 1.90028183e-02
 6.83852785e-04 8.28912467e-05 2.07228117e-05 8.91080902e-04
 5.80238727e-03 3.39854111e-03 1.11488727e-02 6.21684350e-05
 3.31564987e-04 8.18551061e-03 7.46021220e-04 3.52287798e-04
 6.21684350e-05 1.50862069e-02 2.48673740e-04 1.53141578e-02
 4.64190981e-03 4.14456233e-05 2.27950928e-04 1.73242706e-02
 8.89008621e-03 4.14456233e-04 1.28481432e-03 1.65782493e-04
 3.99950265e-03 7.41876658e-03 3.31564987e-04 1.90649867e-03
 1.24336870e-04 7.39804377e-03 1.07758621e-03 6.21684350e-05
 3.39854111e-03 2.19661804e-03 3.85444297e-03 1.88577586e-03
 3.56432361e-03 1.03614058e-03 2.07228117e-05 4.35179045e-04
 6.90069629e-03 1.86505305e-04 2.27950928e-03 2.90119363e-04
 4.39323607e-03 4.14456233e-05 5.18070292e-04 1.80288462e-03
 4.14456233e-05 4.10311671e-03 3.93733422e-04 4.53829576e-03
 6.21684350e-05 1.80288462e-03 5.38793103e-04 2.01011273e-03
 3.68037135e-02 3.50008289e-02 2.63386936e-02 9.82261273e-03
 1.75729443e-02 2.89497679e-02 1.78423408e-02 2.69396552e-03
 3.04418103e-02 4.35179045e-03 3.29492706e-03 1.59565650e-03
 1.67854775e-03 1.58115053e-02 1.83604111e-02 2.34375000e-02
 1.50033156e-02 1.38221154e-02 4.66263263e-03 1.92722149e-03
 1.59565650e-03 1.09830902e-03 3.43998674e-03 2.17589523e-03
 3.81299735e-03 1.11281499e-02 1.45059682e-04 1.91271552e-02
 1.96866711e-03 4.55901857e-04 5.80238727e-04 6.21684350e-05
 1.86505305e-04 6.15467507e-03 8.84864058e-03 3.73010610e-04
 1.24336870e-03 7.04575597e-04 1.03614058e-04 7.66744032e-04
 1.24336870e-04 4.14456233e-04 2.07228117e-04 4.97347480e-04
 1.61637931e-03 1.45059682e-04 1.20192308e-03 3.43998674e-03
 1.24336870e-04 3.00480769e-03 1.71999337e-03 1.03614058e-04
 2.07228117e-03 3.33637268e-03 1.69927056e-03 2.56962865e-03
 3.21203581e-03 5.38793103e-04 2.92191645e-03 4.24817639e-03
 4.90508952e-02 3.35709549e-03 6.00961538e-04 2.27950928e-04
 6.19612069e-03 1.59565650e-02 4.14456233e-03 1.52934350e-02
 8.70358090e-04 8.28912467e-05 1.24336870e-04 1.86505305e-03
 8.28912467e-05 1.80288462e-03 1.99767905e-02 2.63179708e-03
 2.69396552e-04 8.35129310e-03 7.08720159e-03 3.10842175e-04
 2.96336207e-03 3.46070955e-03 1.13975464e-03 3.58504642e-03
 5.59515915e-04 2.23806366e-03 2.07228117e-04 4.43468170e-03
 1.40915119e-02 1.15011605e-02 4.18600796e-03 4.20673077e-03
 7.41876658e-03 5.22214854e-03 2.07228117e-05 1.09001989e-02
 1.69927056e-03 1.45059682e-02 6.77635942e-03 1.46095822e-02
 3.25969828e-02 2.21734085e-03 9.94694960e-04 6.21684350e-05
 1.94794430e-03 3.62649204e-03 4.31034483e-03 3.25348143e-03
 1.28481432e-03 3.31564987e-04 3.93733422e-04 1.03614058e-04
 1.84433024e-03 1.71999337e-03 1.45059682e-04 2.73541114e-03
 2.25878647e-03 2.92191645e-03 3.31564987e-04 1.07758621e-03
 2.27950928e-04 1.65782493e-04 4.35179045e-04 1.26409151e-03
 1.51276525e-03 2.48673740e-04 4.14456233e-05 2.07228117e-04
 2.79757958e-03 8.28912467e-05 2.30023210e-03 1.24336870e-03
 3.31564987e-04 6.21684350e-05 9.11803714e-04 2.07228117e-05
 4.35179045e-04 2.07228117e-05 2.27950928e-04 1.16047745e-03
 9.73972149e-04 3.31564987e-04 3.64721485e-03]
```

Its an array of 235 items, It makes sense, because if i group my dataset on category it contains 235 categories. But its missing the Category label with the probability. Does someone know why? Or can someone give me the right directions?

I want to create a flask web application where i can see the probability of the prediction, if its greater then 0.80% for example i can assign it.

Can someone help me with this? I am struggling a couple of days with this issue now :(.

My complete code looks like this

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

#open file
data = pd.read_csv('cats.csv',sep=';')
data['length'] = data['Product Name'].str.len()

#remove all puncs
def text_process(mess):
    # Check characters to see if they are in punctuation
    nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]
    # Join the characters again to form the string.
    nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)
    # Now just remove any stopwords
    return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english') if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('dutch')]


# Might take awhile...
bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process).fit(data['Product Name'])

# Print total number of vocab words
messages_bow = bow_transformer.transform(data['Product Name'])
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(messages_bow)
messages_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(messages_bow)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
spam_detect_model = MultinomialNB().fit(messages_tfidf, data['Category Path'])

message4 = "Some input data from flask web app "
bow4 = bow_transformer.transform([message4])
tfidf4 = tfidf_transformer.transform(bow4)

predicted =  spam_detect_model.predict_proba(tfidf4)[0]
print(predicted)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think the labels are not stored in the model. You may need to re-attach names to the predicted classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, with the `.classes_` attribute you can find the predicted classes. Then you have to concatenate the `predict_proba` together with the `.classes_`.

In Python it looks like this

```
message4 = "Jeans model Ornella met iets kortere pijpen Van"
bow4 = bow_transformer.transform([message4])
tfidf4 = tfidf_transformer.transform(bow4)
counter = 0
predicted = spam_detect_model.predict_proba(tfidf4)
for x in spam_detect_model.classes_:
  proba  = round(predicted[0][counter],2)
  if proba > 0.01:
      print(x + ' probility '+ str(proba) + '%')
  counter +=1
```

What returns, depending on the if statement:

```
Dames%26gt%3BKleding%26gt%3BJeans%26gt%3BBoyfriend+Jeans probility 0.04%
Dames%26gt%3BKleding%26gt%3BJeans%26gt%3BMom+Jeans probility 0.12%
Dames%26gt%3BKleding%26gt%3BJeans%26gt%3BSkinny+Fit+Jeans probility 0.26%
Dames%26gt%3BKleding%26gt%3BJeans%26gt%3BStraight+Fit+Jeans probility 0.02%
Dames%26gt%3BKleding%26gt%3BPlus+Size%26gt%3BJeans probility 0.03%
```